# How to select an item for a category using a comma separated string in a row (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, string

I've been trying to resolve this for 6 days with no luck and my brain is burning...

I have a table ITEMS

In table ITEMS I have an item_cat_id row which corresponds to a specific category (lets suppose is '12') BUT also have a row with a string separated by commas (item_extensions) which corresponds to other categories like (14, 21, 3)

In the table CATEGORIES I have the category_id row (among other obvious rows needed).

When I go to category 12 it shows the items that are in that category:($cat is the var I pass) > xxx.php?cat_id=12

```
$rs_products = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM items WHERE item_public = 'Y' AND item_cat_id =:cat ORDER BY item_order ASC, item_id DESC");
$rs_products->bindValue(':cat', $cat, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$rs_products->execute();
```

Until that point everything goes ok, BUT...

I could do an array of all item_extensions

```
$rs_items = $conn->prepare("SELECT item_extensions FROM items");
$rs_items->execute();
$array = $rs_items -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($array as $row) {
$ext[] = $row['item_extensions'];
}
$m = (array_filter($ext));// to clean empty results from items that has no extension
$catadd = implode(',', $m);
```

I could identify the items for the above array

```
$rs_productsb = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM items WHERE item_extensions IN (".$catadd." ) ");
$rs_productsb->execute();
$array2 = $rs_productsb -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($array2 as $row2) {
$item[] = $row2['item_id'];
}
$catadd2 = implode(',', $item);
```

But I can't resolve how to do this last step, How do I show a result when I go to category 21 (which has no direct item associated) but I want to show the item that has this category in the (item_extensions) row?

Comment: Comma separated values are not good way to handle related data in RDBMS. I guess, you need to follow `many to many` relationship structure by creating a third party table.

Comment: Yes, I'm in that way, the fact is I tried with comma separated values because of the structure of the site in other sections but you are right...thanks anyway !!!